# XML error in browser when adding a new node in Java

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, dom, nodes

I've got this XML file:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <fname>Tim</fname>
    <lname>DiRusso</lname>
    <languages>Java,PHP</languages>
    <days>Monday,Tuesday</days>
    <frameworks>NodeJS,Django</frameworks>
  </person>
</persons>
```

I'm trying to add a new 'person' node to go inside the persons block like this:

```
InputStream is = sc.getResourceAsStream(_filename);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document document = db.parse(is);

Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
Element personNode =  (Element) root.getElementsByTagName("person").item(0);
Element newPerson = document.createElement("person");

Element firstName = document.createElement("fname");
firstName.setTextContent("AppendedNode");
newPerson.appendChild(firstName);

personNode.appendChild(newPerson);

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(res.getWriter());
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

And Chrome is giving the error (this happens on the transform line):

```
error on line 11 at column 11: Extra content at the end of the document
```

I can't figure out why or how extra content would be at the end of the document?

Comment: *Chrome is giving the error* how/where are you executing the code ?

Comment: @Ravi Deployed on a Tomcat server within Eclipse.

Comment: `Element personNode =  (Element) root.getElementsByTagName("person").item(0);` why ?

Comment: @Ravi To append the new node after that existing node.  I've also tried to append the new node to root and get the same error.  I feel like I'm appending to the wrong place but there isn't anywhere else to try

Comment: @Ravi Just fixed.  I had a line            `out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Form</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>");` that was throwing off the tags in the browser